# SwiftUI if number is above 30

Tags: swiftui

So I am trying to show a different UI if a number is above 34

However somehow the code is triggering above 3. Not quite sure why it triggering at > 3 instead of > 34

```
if self.speed > "\(String(34))" {
                VStack(alignment: .center){
                    Text("YOUR SPEED IS")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .lineSpacing(30)
                        .padding(20)
                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                            
                    Text(String(self.speed))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .lineSpacing(30)
                        .padding(20)
                        .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                                            
                    Text("Our system detected you driving or moving too fast")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .light, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        
                    
                    
                }.frame(minWidth: 0,
                        maxWidth: .infinity,
                        minHeight: 0,
                        maxHeight: .infinity,
                        alignment: .topLeading
                ).background(Color.black)
            }
```

I am wondering if I am doing the if statement correctly?

I am getting the speed from the users location (note I need the speed in KM)

```
static let Speed = 0


 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        lastKnownLocation = locations.last
    
        
        if(lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.latitude != LocationManager.LMlat && lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.longitude != LocationManager.LMlong)
        {
          
           
            
//This fetches the users speed and coverts it to KM
            
let km = String(format: "%.0f",lastKnownLocation!.speed * 3.6)
            
LocationManager.Speed = Int(km) ?? 0
           
//We then check to see if the users speed is above 2.5km and if so we update.
            if(km > String(2.5)){
                print("Updating latest location")
                print("speed: \(km)")
                LocationManager.LMlat = lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.latitude
                LocationManager.LMlong = lastKnownLocation!.coordinate.longitude
                updateServerLocation(latitude: LocationManager.LMlat, longitude:  LocationManager.LMlong, speed: km)
            }
        }
        
}
```

Note it won't let me save it as an Int

Comment: Because you are comparing the numbers as strings.  "4" comes after "34"  lexicographically.

Comment: `self.speed` must be a `String` or else your code wouldn't compile.  How are you getting that value? Could it be stored as an `Int` or `Double` instead?

Comment: @vacawama it won't let me save the speed as an Int or a Double

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I compare number with string format directly in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684260/can-i-compare-number-with-string-format-directly-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if Int(self.speed)! > 34 {
```

or

```
if Int(self.speed) ?? 0 > 34 {
```

Instead of turning `34` into a String, turn `self.speed` into an Int or Double.

*Honestly though, self.speed should probably be an Int to begin with.*

Comment: I converted it to Int and got it working. with if self.speed > 34